# QC ALM ( QC 11) REST Api 400 Error while Authentication

Tags: java, rest, hp-quality-center

I am trying to access QC 11 using Rest api in Java.

I am following API reference in the manual provided by HP.
Following is basic step for login authentication.

> > Non-Web Application Authorization Client queries the is-authenticated resource and sends no authentication headers. This
> >     step is optional.
>
> GET /qcbin/rest/is-authenticated
>
> Server refuses request and returns reference to authentication point.
>
> HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized  WWW-Authenticate: LWSSO
>   realm=http://[server]:[port]/qcbin/authentication-point
>
> Client sends a valid Basic Authentication header to the authentication
>   point.
>
> GET /qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate  Authorization: Basic
>   ABCDE123
>
> Server validates the Basic authentication headers, creates a new
>   LW-SSO token and returns it as LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY.
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK  Set-Cookie: LWSSO_COOKIE_KEY={cookie}
>
> The application can now access data and services using the token. At
>   the end of the session, log off to discard the token.

Here is my java code.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            String encoding = Base64.encodeBase64String("demoUser:demoUser123".getBytes());
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://HOST_VALUE:PORT_VALUE/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate");
            //httpGet.setHeader("GET", "/qcbin/authentication-point/authenticate");
            httpGet.setHeader("Authorization:", "Basic " + encoding);
            HttpResponse response;



            httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope("proxyHost", 8080),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials("userName", "Password"));




            response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);


            System.out.println(response.getAllHeaders().toString());
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().toString());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
```

It gives me output as

> [Lorg.apache.http.Header;@159e154 HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Output from
>   Server ....

I am new to REST by using Java. Can anyone help?
Any examples for connecting to ALM using REST and fetching data?

Comment: There is a java api: [ALM JAVA API](http://code.google.com/p/alm-java-api/)

Comment: @gonella Broken link.

Comment: @Dennis, Found a new link => [ALM Rest API](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/alm/en/12.50/api_refs/REST_TECH_PREVIEW/ALM_REST_API_TP.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solved the problem.**

The problem was in base64 encoding !
If you are converting string to base64 encoded string... if result is greater than 76 char. it adds new line ! 
even if  its less than 76

So solution was

```
encoding = encoding.replaceAll("\n", "");
```